# Classic asp replace text combinations

Tags: string, ms-access, asp-classic, replace, query-string

I'm trying to accomplish this.

I'm searching for a phone number from a msAccess2000 Database through a Classic ASP website.

The same phone number can stored in the Database as one of the following.

```
(212) 212-2122
212)2122122
2122122122
212-212-2122
212-2122122
```

And many other combinations, you get the idea.

Ideally I would do something like

```
strWhere ="Where replace(replace(Phone,'(',''),'-','') = '" & replace(replace(strPhone,"(",""),"-","") & "'"
```

But MS ACCESS doesn't allow (at least my version) to call the replace function remotely.

Which leaves me with one choice I can think of, create a function that iterates through all replaced combination and add it to the query like this:

```
 strWhere ="Where Phone in (" & PhoneReplace(strPhone) & ");"
```

the function should produce a string with all combinations in this format.
    '2122122122','(2122122122','(212)2122122',......

**How do best write that function?**

Have a better idea?

Comment: Ouch. Access and classic ASP. Must be fun. I don't suppose you have the ability to clean up your data so that it's only the digits? Or maybe add a new column to the table which has only the digits?

Comment: If you can do `LIKE`, you could do `where Phone like '%2%1%2%2%1%2%2%1%2%2%'` - not that I'd recommend this...

Comment: Thanks @joe-enos this definitely is an option. Wonder how fast MS Acess can handle such a query.

Comment: Actually, it probably wouldn't be much worse than the one with all the `replace`s - in either case it wouldn't be able to use an index, so it would run through all the records anyway. How big a table is it?

Comment: shy of 1k rows. grows like 25-35 records per week.

Comment: You should have nothing to worry about then - that should easily work. You could probably even retrieve the entire table and do your filtering in the app without even noticing a performance difference.

Comment: @JoeEnos Add the above to your answer and I will apply it as the accepted answer. thanks.

Comment: Done - LIKE added to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No promises, but Bing-Fu got me this to add the `Replace` feature to your query (from [tech-archive.net](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Access/microsoft.public.access.queries/2005-04/msg02846.html))

Create a new module:

```
Function ReplaceText(StringIn as String) as String 
Dim NewString as String 
NewString = Replace(StringIn,"xyz","abc") 
ReplaceText = NewString 
End function
```

Call it from the query:

```
ChangedText:ReplaceText([FieldName])
```

Another alternative would be to use `LIKE` and put wildcards everywhere - this will allow any format to come in, and assuming your value always contains 10 numbers, and the search criteria contains 10 numbers, it will only find valid matches.

```
where Phone like '%2%1%2%2%1%2%2%1%2%2%'
```

Also, with so few records in your table, you could probably even retrieve the entire table and do your filtering in the app without even noticing a performance difference.

Comment: Thanks @joe-enos Don't think I can add a MS Access function remotely. Downloading the mdb file and reuploading is risky because its a live DB.

Comment: I created a small function that adds '%' after each char and it works fine. Thanks